# add child key to plist programmatically (iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone, plist

does anybody know how to add a child key to the root key programmatically in a plist?

sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSString *path = @"path/to/some/file";
 NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
 [plist setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"aKey"];
 [plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
 [plist release];
```

Note that you cannot write inside your own bundle; you'll have to copy the file to somewhere within your app's sandbox. Check out the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code example but I can't get it work this way. If I try like you described in your example it just sets the value for the key, but I'm trying to add a sub key (add an sub key (array) named movies to the first key, which is generally the root key).

Comment: ok, i solved my problem. instead of trying to create a key programmatically in a plist file which is located in the application documents directory, I created a plist file with the key manually in the resource folder and then i copy this file to the app documents directory.

Comment: Noah's code should work, with Mutable Dictionaries values for keys can be pointers to other arrays or dictionaries.  For example: [plist setObject:moviesArray forKey@"Movies"] would do what you are asking.  If the movies key doesn't exist then it would create it.